High frequency gate signalling from TLP 250
I am trying to work with MOSFET 10n60 at high frequency but the gate to source output and the drain to source is not right at high frequency.Blue signal is drain to source and yellow signal is gate to source


Define "not right". What did you expect to be different, and why?

I expect it to be the same as the low frequency output. No shift between them

Are you sure that the low frequency trace has no such shift?

yes I have attached a photo of the output at the low frequency

But zoom in to the same time scale that you used on the high-frequency plot. Look at both the rising and falling edges. I think you'll find that they look pretty similar.
